# attaching windows service to skype Public Api

Tags: c++, skype

I need to capture the Skype Event through Windows Service.Skype like Call etc.

I am trying to register the Skype Notification but it failing.

Whether Windows Service allows Registering Skype Event or not?If not how can we achieve this.

Comment: Try here http://developer.skype.com

Comment: Have you attached skype from win service??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows service in general allows to register events from Skype but first you must define:

1) Are you going to use Skype4COM (Desktop API) to communicate with one of standard Skype clients.

2) OR are you going to build your own Skype client using SkypeKit SDK?

The case 1 allows exchanging data only if some Skype client is running

but case 2 can work even while no user is logged in but it requires much more effort.

Comment: Can you provide any link to documentation where said that I can attach skype from win service using skype4com.

Comment: There is no reason you couldn't - just you still need Skype client running.. so for example your service can run but can't work while all users are logged off..

Comment: I can't figure out how to connect to Skype from service. I think it is impossible, because Attach method registers window message which mean you must have window. Have win service which uses skype4com to attach Skype?

Comment: I have such service - it is not impossible. You are not obligated to have a window.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to have Skype4COM in windows service